# Showing two functions are uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

I have no idea how to prove this detail (uniformly continuous) about these functions because they're defined to $\infty$.
I need the general mindset to prove it, or any ideas. Thanks in advance.

$$
f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x+1},
 \;\;x\in[0,\infty[
$$
and
$$
g(x)=\sqrt{x}\sin\frac{1}{x},\;\; x\in]0,\infty[
$$

I have problems with the algebra, and I do not think that it is possible to use Heine–Cantor theorem here.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily verify it directly. You want to show that for ever $\epsilon > 0$ there exist a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $|x-y|<\delta$ with $x,y\in [0,\infty)$, then $|f(x)-f(y)| = |\frac{x^2}{x+1}-\frac{y^2}{y+1}|<\epsilon$.

Consider the next inequalities:

\begin{align*}|f(x)-f(y)| &= \left|\frac{x^2}{x+1}-\frac{y^2}{y+1}\right|\\
&= \left|\frac{x^2(y+1) - y^2(x+1)}{(x+1)(y+1)}\right|\\
&= \left|\frac{(x+xy+y)(x-y)}{(x+1)(y+1)}\right|\\
&= \frac{(x+xy+y)}{(x+1)(y+1)}|x-y| \\
&= \frac{(x+xy+y)}{(x+xy+y)+1}|x-y| \\
&\leq |x-y|
\end{align*}

So picking $\delta = \epsilon$ is enough, since  $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y| < \delta = \epsilon$.

The other function seems a little bit trickier, but the reasoning is similar.

Hint: $|\sqrt{x}\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - \sqrt{y}\sin(\frac{1}{y})|\leq |\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}|$